# converting class based component with state to functional component with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, components, react-hooks

I have this componet with state, here when the user is online it increases the count. I want to change it to functional component with hooks, which I have done below

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isOnline: true,
    count: 1
  }

  handleOnline = () => {
    if (!this.state.isOnline) {
      this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1
      }, () => {
        this.setState({ isOnline: !this.state.isOnline })
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({ isOnline: !this.state.isOnline })
    }

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>online ==> {this.state.isOnline ? 'Online' : 'Offline'}</h1>
        <h1>count ==> {this.state.count}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleOnline}>Toggle</button>
      </div>
    );

  }
}
```

Here is my conversion to functional component with hooks,

```
const App = () => {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(true)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1)

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (!isOnline) {
      setIsOnline(!isOnline)
      setCount(count + 1)
    } else {
      setIsOnline(!isOnline)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>online ==> {isOnline ? 'Online' : 'Offline'}</h1>
      < h1 > count ==> {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Toggle</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In the class based component, I have read not to use setState one after another so I used the callback function in this.setState like this

```
this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1
      }, () => {
        this.setState({ isOnline: !this.state.isOnline })
      })
```

Now, in the functional component I have used setCount and setIsOnline one after another is it good ???

```
const handleClick = () => {
    if (!isOnline) {
      setIsOnline(!isOnline)
      setCount(count + 1)
    } else {
      setIsOnline(!isOnline)
    }
```

*I have read to use useEffect for callbacks, but all I get is infinite loop*. Even though both of my components work and give me the desired result . I wanted to know if i must use useEffect for the callback or if my implementation with hooks in functional component is correct???

Answer (score 1):

This implementation is correct, yes we should not set one state after the other because setState works asynchronously but since you are only setting two states so its fine.
Although you can also keep one state object instead of both separate states i.e

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ count: 1, isOnline: true });
```

And then you can set both object keys in a single setState, like:

```
setState(() => ({
  count: 1,
  isOnline: false,
}))
```

Also in the class based approach you have used a callback but you actually don't need that, you can use single setState for setting both states i.e.

```
this.setState(() => ({
  count: this.state.count + 1, 
  isOnline: !this.state.isOnline ,
}))
```

**Another important note:**

Try to use functional set state as I use in examples above, as it reduces the risk of being caught into React state asynchronous issues.

Comment: Why should we not set state one after the other?

Comment: Its not that we should not setState one after the other its not recommended if you have too many states and possibly when one state might be effecting the other state value,and since it sets asynchronously its quite possible that the state you set at first might got set after the last one. For such kind of situations its also recommend to use functional setState which sets the states in order..

Comment: State is set in the order you call setState. It is asynchronous but respects the order you call it in. Functional set state is used when setting a value depends on the previous value, not just any previous state.

Comment: React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.

Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.
You should always do this kind of manipulation with a functional approach, supplying the state and props and returning the new state based on the former. For reference : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/get-pro-with-react-setstate-in-10-minutes-d38251d1c781/

Comment: The functional setState you are talking about is irrelevant when using hooks, as passing a function to `setCount` for example, only allows the previous `count` value to be accessible. The original statement you made was "we should not set state one after the other because state updates asynchronously".  What you really mean is "you should not set state for one value, then set state for another value based on the first state change, as state updates asynchronously so the first change has not happened yet." There's nothing wrong with calling `setState` multiple times in a row.

Comment: Ypu also say "its quite possible that the state you set at first might got set after the last one". This is incorrect, state is always updated in the same order that you set it. What you're talking about is when you pass `count` to `setCount`, twice in a row, the first `count` might not have changed yet. But you misunderstand. The first count **never** changes. It doesn't sometimes change and sometimes not. State is immutable.

Comment: I dint talked about using functional setState when using hooks. Also, I said, we can setState one after the other but its not recommended when we have so many setStates and are setting a state and using that state value in another setState.
However, I agree with your last point . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Calling set state one after the other is totally fine and is the correct thing to do here:

```
const handleClick = () => {
  if (!isOnline) {
    setIsOnline(!isOnline)
    setCount(count + 1)
  } else {
    setIsOnline(!isOnline)
  }
}
```

State is updated asychronously, which means that your state variables `isOnline` and `count` don't actually change until your component re-renders. Calling `setCount` and `setIsOnline` doesn't update these variables, but tells React to update on the next render.

This is why you can't do something like this:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1)
    setCount(count + 1)
}
```

The count would be incremented by 1, NOT by 2.

Why?

Because the value `count` has not been updated yet, since we have to wait until re-render before it gets updated. That means `count` has the same value the entire way through the function - it never changes. So you can call `setCount(count + 1)` a million times and the value will only ever increment by 1.

This is what people mean when they say you should use the set state callback function.

This is the set state callback function:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(prev => prev + 1)
    setCount(prev => prev + 1)
}
```

This works as expected, and `count` will now be incremented by 2.

If we pass a function like this `prev => prev + 1` to set state, React will pass the **most recent value** to the function.

The rule is:

**Every time you use the old state value to set the new state value - pass a function to set state.**

So although your current implementation does work, you should really be passing a function to set state on `count` since you are depending on previous state:

```
const handleClick = () => {
  if (!isOnline) {
    setIsOnline(!isOnline)
    setCount(prev => prev + 1)
  } else {
    setIsOnline(!isOnline)
  }
}
```

Usually you should do this for your boolean value too, for example:

```
setIsOnline(prev => !prev)
```

but since you're using `isOnline` in your if statement, you shouldn't do that here as the `prev` value may be different than the value your `if` uses.